# How to fix property 'num_rows' of non-object error

Tags: php, mysqli

```php
  if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {                
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     code here..}`
```

Above is my php code, but always server saying below error.

> Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in...

Comment: Why is this tagged as java?

Comment: What is the $result?

Comment: Always show full code where you stuck.

Comment: $result seems to be null. Show us the code where you query for the result.

Answer (score -1):

Try This >

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result){
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {                
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     code here..}`
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it just hides it.